# 2 Phase Locking and Deadlocks in DBMS

Tags: concurrency, locking, rdbms

Hi good people of stack overflow.

I have a question regarding the functionality of 2PL and deadlocks. I don't know why this is so hard for me to understand, but I've tried making a pseudo sequence diagram to ease the understanding.

[image: Pseudo sequence diagram of 2PL]

Is my understanding of 2PL correct here? I'm aware of the deadlock handling isn't specific to 2PL.

Is it correctly understood that IF T1 transaction has aquired a writelock (exclusive) and T2 then tries to aquire a readlock, that T2 then is forced to wait?

I know that only one can have a writelock, but as I understand 2PL, then if a transaction is modifying (having the writelock), then another transaction cannot read (aquire the readlock).

Looking forward to your answers - have a great weekend. :-)

/Ben